# Super slow file transfer via OTG and system lag Android 9

Tags: usb-on-the-go

So I'm using a new Lenovo TB-8505X with Android 9 and I've tried several file managers and still when I'm trying to transfer files to any of my USB sticks the speed is too slow, like one mb and even gets slower and the system starts to lag, when the transfer is complete the system resumes its normal work! At first it starts to transfer fast, like instantly 10-20% of the file and then it slows down!

On my old Lenovo Tab Essentials with Android 5 everything transfers fast and the system doesn't lag! Why is that and what can be done about it?

I've already tried to enable USB Debugging and all that, to no avail!

Do any of you guys have this problem, seems like a Pie's problem...

Is it even solvable?

Device works flawlessly except for this one problem!

P.S. Doesn't seem like a warranty problem or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the USB OTG adapter.

on some controllers I have to flip the USB around, one side of the USB C runs at USB 2.0 speeds.

The other side will run at 3.0 speeds.

If your tablet has a full USB port - then im baffled. running fast at start then slowing down is usually a sign of write caching. sometimes it doesnt measure the speeds right.

Comment: What do you mean full USB port? Just a micro USB for charging! Adapter also has on one side a micro USB and on the other a regular USB, same with my OTG cable, they both work just fine with my other tablet! I'm baffled myself! But it's not a warranty issue, like, should I try to replace it in the shop? Coz doesn't seem reasonable, device works great! Aha, maybe speed is too high, what can be done about it?

Comment: I'm thinking, should I try a factory reset? Would it even help, Lenovo support said that I should try! So don't want to, it's like a Windows reinstall, lol! Although I have a backup!

Comment: Sounds like the tablet has a USB 2 Port. That means the best speed will be about 40MBs. This might just be normal for that tablet, I always get USB 3 tablets for this reason.

Comment: Even 5-6mb would do, but when the speed halts to zero now and slows down the device, that's no go! See there: https://support.google.com/android/thread/20866882?hl=en So the problem is Android P on many devices can't be switched to File Transfer and even when I set File Transfer in the dev mode it still doesn't solve the problem! So it's not normal at all!

Comment: I'll get a new device in May with USB C and USB 3 for sure and Android 10, but so far I'm on this one, lol!